# Python pass a file as argument

Tags: python, mp3

I've been working on a Python problem for sometime now. I'm trying to use the Echoprint API to sort my music out. So i'm writing some code that does that for me.

This is how the API works :

1. Takes in a song name as a command line arg.
2. Gives the appropriate result.

But i'm writing a script that has to perform this "internally". As in, the script should take the files and perform the lookup and output the results to the terminal. (basically - NO COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS SUPPLIED )

So is there anyway as to pass files into a function ? 
I know this sounds silly but it's a problem i'm not able to solve.

If i use os.walk(), etc it returns a str object to my lookup function as a parameter. I want the audio file to be passed as a parameter.

Here's the code which takes in the song as a command line arg :

```
import sys
import os

import pyechonest.config as config
import pyechonest.song as song

config.CODEGEN_BINARY_OVERRIDE = os.path.abspath("/Users/******/python/minger/echoprint-codegen-master/echoprint-codegen")
config.ECHO_NEST_API_KEY='*****'

def lookup(file):
# Note that song.identify reads just the first 30 seconds of the file
    fp = song.util.codegen(file)
    if len(fp) and "code" in fp[0]:
        # The version parameter to song/identify indicates the use of echoprint
        result = song.identify(query_obj=fp, version="4.11")
        print "Got result:", result
        print result[0]
        if len(result):
            print "Artist: %s (%s)" % (result[0].artist_name, result[0].artist_id)
            print "Song: %s (%s)" % (result[0].title, result[0].id)
        else:
            print "No match. This track may not be in the database yet."
    else:
        print "Couldn't decode", file


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Usage: %s <audio file>" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)
    lookup(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

From there, http://echonest.github.io/remix/apidocs/pyechonest.util-module.html#codegen

the method you use has signature

```
codegen(filename, start=0, duration=30)
```

so that it is the filename that has to be passed as an argument... not the file itself...

Ex use here http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@y@pyechonest-7.1.0@pyechonest@song.py/371/util.codegen

```
if filename:
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            query_obj = util.codegen(filename, start=codegen_start, duration=codegen_duration)
            if query_obj is None:
                raise Exception("The filename specified: %s could not be decoded." % filename)
```